# Does a virtual machine reserve parts of my hardware?

Tags: virtual-machine

If i would create a VM would it permanentley reserve parts of my GPU, CPU and Ram? I know that it splits the drive it is installed on, but does it also split other hardware components even if it is not running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually RAM is reserved only while the VM is running. (And then not necessarily all of it upfront – e.g. VirtualBox appears to allocate host memory on-demand, although this varies from hypervisor to hypervisor.)

CPU time is *not* reserved at all; the VM is scheduled like a process and shares CPU time with the host. (A machine's CPU is not 100% busy all the time – in every modern operating system, when the OS is idle the CPU is also idle – which automatically allows virtual machines to only use as much CPU time as they need, without the need for fixed partitioning.)

For GPU it might depend on how it was configured (as VMs usually have *no* GPU access by default). For example, some "PCI pass-through" configurations might permanently detach the GPU from the host as long as the configuration is in place, even if the VM is not running at the time. But in other configurations (e.g. GVT-g or SR-IOV), it seems that GPU processing time is shared (like CPU) and VRAM allocation is "on-demand", although the various documentation seems to be contradictory on the latter.